# Trouble Configuring Amazon S3 Integration for Symfony-Sylius App: Images Upload to Default Storage

Tags: php, symfony, amazon-s3, minio, sylius

I've been trying to set up Amazon S3 integration with my Symfony-Sylius app, but I'm facing an issue where the app continues to upload images to the default storage instead of Amazon S3. Upon checking the request coming from the images, I noticed that the URL points to `127.0.0.1:8000`, while my MinIO server is running on `127.0.0.1:9000`. I suspect that the problem lies with Sylius, but I'm not entirely sure how to proceed.

Here's the relevant part of my services.yaml file:

```yaml
parameters:
    amazon.s3.key:     "%env(AWS_S3_KEY)%"
    amazon.s3.secret:  "%env(AWS_S3_SECRET)%"
    amazon.s3.bucket:  "%env(AWS_S3_BUCKET)%"
    amazon.s3.region:  "%env(AWS_S3_REGION)%"
    amazon.s3.endpoint:  "%env(AWS_S3_ENDPOINT)%"
    amazon.s3.version:  "%env(AWS_S3_VERSION)%"

services:   
    acme.amazon_s3:
        class: Aws\S3\S3Client
        factory: [Aws\S3\S3Client, factory]
        arguments:
            -
                credentials: { key: "%amazon.s3.key%", secret: "%amazon.s3.secret%" }
                region: "%amazon.s3.region%"
                version: "%amazon.s3.version%"
                

    acme.imagine.cache.resolver.aws_s3_resolver:
        class: Liip\ImagineBundle\Imagine\Cache\Resolver\AwsS3Resolver
        arguments:
            - "@acme.amazon_s3"
            - "%amazon.s3.bucket%"
        tags:
            - { name: "liip_imagine.cache.resolver", resolver: "aws_s3_resolver" }
```

And here's my liip_imagine.yaml configuration:

```yaml
liip_imagine:
    resolvers:
        aws_s3_resolver:
            aws_s3:
                client_config:
                    credentials:
                        key:    "%amazon.s3.key%"
                        secret: "%amazon.s3.secret%"
                    region: "%amazon.s3.region%"
                    version: "%amazon.s3.version%"
                bucket: "%amazon.s3.bucket%"
                get_options:
                    Scheme: http
                put_options:
                    CacheControl: "max-age=86400"
    filter_sets:
        cache: ~
        runtime:
            quality: 90
        thumb:
            quality: 75
            filters:
                thumbnail: { size: [ 150, 150 ], mode: outbound }
            cache: aws_s3_resolver
```

I am using:

- PHP version 7.4
- AWS SDK for PHP version 3.277
- Sylius version 1.10

I've checked the configuration and ensured that my Amazon S3 credentials are correctly set in the .env file. However, I'm still unable to get the app to upload images to Amazon S3.

Is there something I'm missing in my configuration, or is there a step I need to take to make Sylius use Amazon S3 for image storage? Any guidance on how to troubleshoot or resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!